# New Windows 8 App Notifications

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to get notifications when an update to a Windows 8 App is released? From what I can tell the only way to do it, is to open the Store application and look in the top right to see if there are new updates available. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure if I would like this especially with all of the updates that everyone is pushing out right now before the official release.

Answer (score 7):

If an update is available to any Windows 8 App, the Windows Store Live Tile indicates the same, with a number determining how many Apps have updates available.

[image]

So you do not have to actually open Windows Store App to check for updates.

Comment: Ah I didn't have that pinned as a tile, so I wasn't seeing it.

Comment: yeah i guessed it!

Comment: @AbhishekGirish: For 3rd party apps I'm sure they can show similar info. as well on their live tiles, right?

Comment: They are free to use the Live Tile in the way they want. They can use it to show notifications, or updates or something else.